# Memcached - How to prevent an item from being removed

Tags: caching, memcached

I'm using the [beitmemcached](http://code.google.com/p/beitmemcached/) client in my application. Is there a way of preventing a cached value from being removed when the cache grows too large? I got some values cached which have to stay in the cache no matter what. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, memcached does not work this way. It is not a data store. Redis and Couchbase are two products that do persistent storage with a memcached (like) interface.